# How to set Outlook 2013 -> File->Options->Mail-> Message Arrial settings through SDK?

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to change below settings using outlook api.

[image]

I am using Visual Studio and outlook intercom library.

Is it possible to change these settings. I have referred this SO question [Change Outlook settings using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454835/change-outlook-settings-using-vsto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no programmatic way to read or set these options, but they are stored in the registry. You can set them directly, but Outlook would need to be restarted.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences]
"PlaySound"
"ChangePointer"
"ShowEnvelope"
"NewmailDesktopAlerts"
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for sharing your valuable knowledge. I tried looking into regedit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\ all the registeries. but could not find the settings for above specified flag. Can you please help ? :)

Comment: Thanks! This helped.

Comment: PlaySound and ChangePointer settings are not available in registery. Can we add them?

Comment: Make sure the checkboxes are checked and then look at the registry values. If unchecked, these values are deleted.